# Stop selling app but upload upgrades

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I would like to know if I can release a new version of my app but don’t sell this new version to new users. I had an app of one of my clients in my iTunes connect account. Then we moved this app to her account (we didn't check the possibility of transferring via Apple this app to her account but instead we uploaded the app again to her account) we are planning to release an upgrade, we would like old users to upgrade to the new version but we don't want to sell the new version in my account anymore. I didn’t deleted the app from my account but instead put the availability date far in the future. I have looked all over and I don't find the information.

Comment: Finally apple lets you transfer apps between accounts. http://www.infoworld.com/t/ios/apple-eases-ios-app-transfers-between-developers-new-owners-220654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Once you push the app to app store, its available to public for sale.

Comment: thanks! I found a not very proper way of doing it but well solves my issue at the moment

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this but off course is not a proper solution. I updated  the app in my account but removed most of the screen shots, left a very short description and increased the price of the app. In this way the app doesn´t sale anymore in my account but old users get to update to a new version.

I strongly recommend anyone who wants to transfer an app to another itunes connect account to check it first with apple. We didn´t see any other solution so we just uploaded it to another account and then realized that this leads to a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Apple gives the possibility to transfer apps to other developer accounts. No more of these problems https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6112013c